# How to cancel the http request after 2 minutes in Javascript form submit?

Tags: javascript, forms, http, timeout, form-submit

Is there any attribute to cancel the request after 2 minutes in Javascript form submit

Javascript code

```
var document = $document[0];
var form = document.createElement('form');
form.setAttribute('method', 'POST');
form.setAttribute('action', '/service/'+url);
var hiddenField = document.createElement('input');
hiddenField.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'filterParam');
hiddenField.setAttribute('value',angular.toJson(input));
form.appendChild(hiddenField);
document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
```

like timeout in http config object.

```
$http({
        method : 'POST',
        **timeout : 120000,**

    }).success(function(data) {

    }).error(function(data, status) {

    });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `window.stop` (In IE, it is `document.execCommand("Stop")`) to abort all pending form submission. The code would be:

```
var document = $document[0];
var form = document.createElement('form');
form.setAttribute('method', 'POST');
form.setAttribute('action', '/service/'+url);
var hiddenField = document.createElement('input');
hiddenField.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'filterParam');
hiddenField.setAttribute('value',angular.toJson(input));
form.appendChild(hiddenField);
document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();

setTimeout(function() {
    try {
        window.stop();
    } catch (exception) {
        document.execCommand('Stop');
    }
}, 120000);
```

According to the [DOM interface](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element) of form element, there is no attribute or method to abort form submission on form element level.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try this today

Comment: @Lakshman is your problem solved? If yes, maybe you can "accept" this answer?

Answer (score 0):

A solution for this approach could be remove the `action` attribute from the form and trigger the ajax call inside a javascript method, where you can manually handle the timeout.

something like:

```
<form>
 ..
 <button ng-click="submit()" />
</form>

$scope.submit = function(){

    var promise= $q.defer();
    $http.get('/actionUrl', {timeout: promise.promise})
    .then(function(resp){

    })

    promise.resolve();  //cancel the request. you can set a timeout here

}
```

Comment: I want to achieve this in form submit